# I am having trouble getting a python script to run when Maya launches

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to run a python script when Maya(2018) is launched on my Mac. I tried creating a file called 'userSetup.py' and placing it in my '/Users/Shared/Autodesk/maya/2018/scripts' directory.

right now the 'userSetup.py' script just has one line:

print 'its working'

so far, I am not able to get the print message to show up in the script editor when I launch Maya(2018).

google, Autodesk website

Comment: it should be in pref/scripts i think

Comment: ../maya/2018/prefs/scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maya usually searches for `userSetup.py` in the paths defined in `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. By default **$HOME/maya/2018/prefs/scripts** directory is added to `PYTHONPATH`when Maya starts. Unless until you are not defining your own `PYTHONPATH` variable, you can put your `userSetup.py` in this directory to work with Maya.

Also most of the time you can find the print or log statements(basically stdout) from the userSetup.py files in the terminal(from where Maya is launched) instead of the Maya Script editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from Maya import cmds

print ('its working')
```